# boost asio stackless corotines - how the switch based macro hack works?

Tags: c++, boost, coroutine, asio

I'm referring to `asio` single header stackless coroutine [implementation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/boost/asio/coroutine.hpp)
The code is based on macro hackery in order achieving state-machine like flow, yet I don't understand fully how it works

Example

```
#define ASIO_CORO_REENTER(c) \
  switch (::asio::detail::coroutine_ref _coro_value = c) \
    case -1: if (_coro_value) \
    { \
      goto terminate_coroutine; \
      terminate_coroutine: \
      _coro_value = -1; \
      goto bail_out_of_coroutine; \
      bail_out_of_coroutine: \
      break; \
    } \
    else /* fall-through */ case 0:
```

- Why at the `case  -1` one checks also for the value of `_coro_value` ? isn't it *MUST* be equal to -1 ?

Comment: Maybe to suppress potential warnings about the value never being read? Similarly the seemingly silly `goto` could be to suppress warnings about unused labels.

Comment: @rustyx isn't consuming the value here `switch (::boost::asio::detail::coroutine_ref _coro_value = c)` means the value is being read/used ?

Comment: @ShmilTheCat I am not sure, but i think author used `if(_coro_value)` instead of `if(true)` both seems to have same effect in this macro.